# Why might I want to use WolframScript instead of mathematica or vise-versa?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What are the differences? Is the only difference that wolfram script is the command line version of mathematica? or are there other benefits?

Comment: OK. I am a university student so I have mathematica for free. I guess then the best use is that scripts I make can run on other machines. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the *WolframScript* is a bit like Julia's REPL (Read-eval-print loop). Sometimes, typing on the command line is much faster than using GUI. However, the Mathematica/Wolfram gives unconverted results such as 1/3, sqrt(17) rather than approximated real numbers.

It's very convenient for short repetitive calculations. For example, I use it to solve exercises or double-check your answer at the end of each section or chapter. It helps me learn faster.